# how to add a marker to basicComponentMap from given coordinates with Nutiteq package?

Tags: android, maps

How to add a marker to BasicComponentMap from given coordinates using the Nutiteq package.
Its quite easy to add a marker if using the current user location, but I want to set a marker in a given location from longitude and latitude.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way:

```
    try {
        Image poiImage = Image.createImage("/res/drawable/gps_marker.png");
        PlaceLabel poiLabel =new PlaceLabel("location");
        Place p = new Place(1, poiLabel, poiImage, lon, lat);
        mapComponent.addPlace(p);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("MAPA", "Couldn't location marker image.");
    }
```

Where mapComponent is BasicMapComponent.